# N-queens problem objective function

Tags: optimization, board-games

I have read about the N-queens problem and I don't understand the following objective function:

$O(board)=N^2/2-L$

$N$ ... number of queens
$L$ ... number of pairs of queens that attack each other

Why they use $N^2/2$? They wrote that it is the number of pairs of queens but I don't understand that can someone maybe explain it to me maybe with visualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective function you describe satisfies two properties:

1. It is maximized at a solution.
2. It is non-negative.

One can think of many other functions satisfying these two properties, for example $\binom{N}{2} - L + C$ for every $C \geq 0$. The exact choice is not so important – indeed, they chose $N^2/2$ whereas they could have chosen $\binom{N}{2} = N(N-1)/2$.

Comment: So it would also be possible to use $O(board)=L$ and minimize the function? and what is the advantage of using such objective functions $O(board)=(N2)−L+C$, $O(board)=N2/2−L$ instead of my example? - maybe it is a stupid question

Comment: I have no idea on what algorithm you are using, but generally speaking, you could minimize $L$, or $L^2$, or $e^L$, or maximize $1/L$; these objectives are all equivalent. A given algorithm might make use of the actual value of the objective function, and then which function you use could make a difference.

Comment: A sorry I totally forgot to say that the paper I read uses the Hill Climbing algorithm

Comment: I answered your question as stated. If you have any further questions, please ask another one, and provide all details that seem relevant. In particular, *hill climbing* is a meta-algorithm with many possible implementations.